# Why does '\n' not work, and what does $/ mean?

Tags: ruby

Why doesn't this code work:

```
"hello \nworld".each_line(separator = '\n') {|s| p s}
```

while this works?

```
"hello \nworld".each_line(separator = $/) {|s| p s}
```

Comment: Note that `each_line(separator = foo)` is quite bad style. `separator = foo; each_line(separator)` is much more readable - assuming creating a local variable named `separator` was actually your intention. Otherwise just `each_line(foo)`.

Comment: @sawa thanks for making correction of my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A 10 second google yielded this:

```
$/ is the input record separator, newline by default.
```

The first one doesn't work because you used single quotes. Backslash escape sequences are ignored in single quoted strings. Use double quotes instead:

```
"hello \nworld".each_line(separator = "\n") {|s| p s}
```

Answer (score 5):

First, newline is the default. All you need is

```
"hello \nworld".each_line {|s| p s}
```

Secondly, single quotes behave differently than double quotes. `'\n'` means a literal backslash followed by the letter n, whereas `"\n"` means the newline character.

Last, the special variable $/ is the record separator which is "\n" by default, which is why you don't need to specify the separator in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Simple [`gsub!`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub%21) your string with valid `"\n"` new line character:

```
text = 'hello \nworld'
text.gsub!('\n', "\n")
```

After that `\n` character will act like newline character.